# I want to fetch serviceData id like 3 data the id in the url and i want only the one record where id is 3

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

import React from 'react'
import Servicedata from './Componants/Data/ServiceDetailsData';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

```
const ServiceDetails =()=> {
  const {uid} = useParams();
  {Servicedata.map(function(data,arr){
    return(
      <>
        if (data.id===uid) {
          console.log(uid)
        }
      </>
    )
  })}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import React from 'react';
import Servicedata from './Componants/Data/ServiceDetailsData';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const ServiceDetails = () => {
  const { uid } = useParams();
  
  return (
    <>
      {Servicedata.filter(item => item.id === uid).map(item => (
        <div key={item.id}>{item.id}</div>
      ))}
    </>
  )
}
```